# Non-Linearities ADC Reading on ESP32

Tags: microcontroller, adc, esp32

I'm using ADC pin in ESP32 WROOM to determine the voltage reading from them (GPIO34, GPIO35, GPIO36, GPIO39) but the reading is not accurate aka non-linear.

What I have done is:

1. I take the actual reading using a multimeter and compare to what the ESP32 reads on those pins by using a potentiometer by varying the voltage on that pin (from 0.1V -> 3.3V based on the ADC reading)
2. I put those numbers into an excel sheet to plot the error in the following columns :
   ADC_READING_VOLTAGE | MULTIMETER_READING | ERROR (MULTIMETER_READING - ADC_READING_VOLTAGE)
3. Then I get a trendline equation from the error plot and add the error margin to the ADC_READING_VOLTAGE so that I could actually get the real value of the reading (MULTIMETER_READING)

```
voltage_reading = analogRead(adc_pin)/4095 *3.3V // to get the actual reading
```

The method that I've tried though gives a slightly better result, but still not good enough (the reading is still off by +- 0.2V)

Has anyone deal with this before? Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Have you tried: voltage_reading = (analogRead(adc_pin)*3.3V)/4095 ? The ADC should be much better.

Comment: and on what you are making these assumptions, can you confirm that the power supply has no noise, your wiring has no capacitance? +- 0.2V seems more than good in non-lab conditions

Answer (score 1):

I'll need your header files to give you a clear solution.

I also came across this issue when I used the `WiFi.h` everything seems to work fine without `WiFi.h`, for some reason the ESP32 analog pins(13,12,14,4..) are HIGH while using `WiFi.h` that's why when you connect the sensors to these pins the value returned is 4095 which is the highest value, I got around this by changing the pins to pin 32, 34, 35, 36 & 39.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by plotting 3 piecewise equation to solve the problem on excel,  reduced the error margin around +-0.02V (although region >3.1V around +-0.05V).

[image: adc_plot_non_linearities_fix]

Comment: If you guys have any other fix, let me know how to simplify it

Comment: I wouldn´t use exponents over x^3. You can´t measure precisely enough to figure the exact values in front of x^4, x^5 and x^6 out. Every value of these tends to be nearly 0. It´s just wasted resources of your esp32 to use them.